# Edit and upload pdf forms

Tags: html, angularjs, pdf, web

I want from my web application to give the opportunity to users to open and edit a template pdf form (and without download it and after upload it again with their changes) to save it directly to server. I use angularjs.

i really appreciate your time!

Comment: i want to notice also that the field i want the client to fill is a digital signature. Thanks

Comment: Do you want the user to edit the form (template), or to fill out the form?

Comment: the form will fill automatically by backend java spring mvc... i want to save the users to download the pdf, insert their digital signature and finally upload it to server... from browsers you can insert the ds but how can i take the new pdf file and save it?

Comment: i want something like this but without the conversion to jpeg

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292126/how-to-edit-a-pdf-in-the-browser-and-save-it-to-the-server

Comment: The standard approach to such a workflow is to provide the pre-filled PDF to the user who downloads it, opens it in Adobe Acrobat (Reader), applies the digital signature, and submits the form back to your server. The submitting can be done automatically in the signing action of the Signature field.

Comment: How do your users sign? Do they have a key pair on their client machine? Is the private key retrievable? Ord they use a signing web service?